# What is the symbol that is used for the universal set in these two textbooks?

Tags: notation

From [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=A2KcCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA351):

[image]

And [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=I61LAc62BvwC&pg=PA174):

[image]

It looks like a squiggly E (\mathcal{E}) or perhaps it is the Greek letter xi (ξ). But I am not sure.

Comment: You should probably ask this on the tex.stackexchange site...

Comment: It’s simply an upper-case script E. `\mathscr{E}` ($\mathscr{E}$) comes a bit closer to it than `\mathcal{E}` ($\mathcal{E}$), though neither is especially close to that particular font.

Comment: @5xum: Why? It’s a straightforward question about the meaning of a piece mathematical notation.

Comment: Actually the OP already knows the **meaning** (the universal set), but wants to know which character it is.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't see this question as asking "what is the meaning of this symbol", especially since both use cases **clearly** state that the symbol means "the universal set". The question is really about what symbol this is, not what it means, and therefore a better fit for tex.SE

Comment: @5xum: Sorry: that was a slip of the mind: I meant to write *identity*, not *meaning* — and I consider that entirely appropriate here.

Comment: @Robert: Yes; see my comment response to **5xum** just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a capital E in a script style font.
It is not $\Xi,\xi$.

[image]

More details can be found on the tex site [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/what-are-all-the-font-styles-i-can-use-in-math-mode).